# Error when running "npm install" in ARM64 Dockerfile with Node.js 18

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, raspberry-pi, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Docker container for my Node.js application using an ARM64 base image with Node.js 18. My Dockerfile seems to be configured correctly, with package.json and package-lock.json in the project's root folder. However, when running the npm install command in the Dockerfile, I get an error with an exit code of 139.

`Dockerfile.arm64`

```
FROM arm64v8/node:14 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM arm64v8/node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```
 => ERROR [builder 4/6] RUN npm install                                              0.3s
------
 > [builder 4/6] RUN npm install:
------
Dockerfile.arm64:11
--------------------
  11 | >>> RUN npm install
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
```

Comment: _"with Node.js 18"_... then why are you using `node:14`?

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue and tried to use below dockerfile FROM statement.

```
FROM arm64v8/node:20.9.0
```

Maybe node.js 18.x has some issue.

use node 20.x